# I need an SQL query that populates column with random numbers within min/max range

Tags: php, sql, random

Okay so I have 2 columns in a table called "user". The columns are called "avatarid" and "avatarrevision"

For my query, I need to populate all row entries for "avatarid" with random numbers between 1 and 7 only where "avatarrevision" currently equals "0".

I have no idea how to write the random number stuff. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `update` and `rand()`:

```
update user
    set avatarid = floor(1 + rand() * 7)
    where avatarrevision = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE user SET avatarid = avatarid + FLOOR(RAND() * (1)) + 7 where avatarrevision = 0;
```